# How to copy the content of a relative folder to the output folder on build

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I have ASP.NET Core web project, which is located in:

`~\Solutions\src\Web\`

I have a second folder, which contains external assemblies:

`~\dependencies\third_party\`

So the *dependencies* and *Solutions* folders are sibling folders. I want to copy all dlls from the *third_party* folder to the output folder of the web project. In my case the output folder is:

`~\Solutions\src\Web\bin\Debug\net461\win7-x64`

I tried using the `copyToOutput` option in project.json:

```
"buildOptions": {,
  "copyToOutput": {
    "include": [ "../../dependencies/third_party/*" ]
  }
}
```

The problem is that this will copy the assemblies in a child folder of the output folder. In my case it copies the assemblies in:

`~\Solutions\src\Web\bin\Debug\net461\win7-x64\dependencies\third_party\{dlls are here}`

Any ideas how to copy the assemblies at the root level of the output folder, not in any sub folders ?

Comment: use a gulp or grunt task and a pre or post compile script

Comment: @aguafrommars, Yes, I thought on using post compile script. The only thing I was not sure was how to get the output directory dynamically. After researching a little bit further, I found that %compile:RuntimeOutputDir% should work for my case. So I'll try something like: `"postcompile": [ "copyDlls.cmd %project:Directory% %compile:RuntimeOutputDir%" ]`

Comment: I think it should be possible to use mappings to do that. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/project-json